# iOS App discussion unable to "log in"

Tags: bug, ios-app

So when user browsing SE using iOS App, and wants to enter to "discussion" generated by SE because of too many comments, this happens (see picture):

[image: unable to log in]

User can not "log in" because of top banner, (I mainly use chrome and I have session in that browser - and don't want to use safari at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click the tiny *click here to hide the notification bar* to be able to log in. I agree, this is far from ideal but it works.

You can also log yourself in using Mobile Safari and then open chat here. The view uses the browser nowadays, so no need to log in here.

Comment: I think yes, I totally missed that link. Thank you :). I think I am going to keep this question here.

Comment: Sure, and it needs to be fixed, but now you have a workaround. (Actually two of them) There is also a feature request to integrate chat in the app, but I don't see that happen very soon.